VMware Error: Processor Does Not Support XSAVE on 32-bit System
I've recently met this error "the processor does not support xsave. this virtual machine cannot be powered" on VMWare while trying to run my Ubuntu on my 32bit PC
I have tried First to download an old ISO version Ubuntu 17 and uneblaed Hyper-V and restart the pc but it doesn't work!
I have also lunch a command line that i got on ChatGPT cpuid.enableXSAVE = "FALSE" , but still doesn't work

AFAIK, the last version of Ubuntu with a 32-bit installer was 16.04. Currently, I'm running 18.04 LTS on 32-bit hardware, by first installing 16.04 then upgrading. Also, I've run 32-bit Windows OS on a 64-bit PC in Oracle's VirtualBox, so you might try that.

unfortunetly VirtualBox can't run on my PC

Why doesn't VirtualBox run on your PC? You should be able to use an older version.

If VirtualBox cannot run on your PC then it also means VMWare cannot run on your PC. Your question needs a great deal more information before we can help you. I also have no idea what word "uneblaed" is supposed to be.  The first thing I would do is make sure the current version of VMWare is installed. What version of Windows?
